# Performance of numpy.searchsorted is poor on structured arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, binary-search

<sub>Sorry in advance if I'm misusing any terms, feel free to correct that.</sub>

I have a sorted array with `dtype` `'<f16, |S30'`. When I use `searchsorted` on its first field, it works really slow (about 0.4 seconds for 3 million items). That is much longer than `bisect` takes to do the same on a plain Python list of tuples.

```
%timeit a['f0'].searchsorted(400.)
1 loops, best of 3: 398 ms per loop
```

However, if I copy the float part to another, separate array, the search is faster than `bisect`:

```
b = a['f0'].copy()

%timeit b.searchsorted(400.)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 945 ns per loop
```

My questions are:

1. Am I doing something wrong or is it a regression in NumPy?
2. Is there a way to circumvent this without duplication of the data?

Answer (score 13):

I remember seeing this some time ago. If I remember correctly, I think searchsorted makes a temporary copy of the data when the data is not contiguous. If I have time later, I'll take a look at the code to confirm that's what's happening (or maybe someone more familiar with the code can confirm this).

In the mean time, if you don't want to restructure your code to avoid using a structured array, your best bet is probably to use `bisect_left(a['f0'], 400.)`. On my machine it's 8x slower than searchsorted on a contiguous array but 1000x faster than searchsorted on a non-contiguous array.

```
In [5]: a = np.arange((6e6)).view([('f0', float), ('f1', float)])

In [6]: timeit a['f0'].searchsorted(400.)
10 loops, best of 3: 51.1 ms per loop

In [7]: timeit a['f0'].copy()
10 loops, best of 3: 51 ms per loop

In [8]: timeit bisect_left(a['f0'], 400.)
10000 loops, best of 3: 52.8 us per loop

In [9]: f0 = a['f0'].copy()

In [10]: timeit f0.searchsorted(400.)
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.85 us per loop
```

Comment: It should be noted that if your array is big enough that the difference between bisect and searchsorted is significant, then the time taken to .copy() that column, use it for searchsorted lookups, then get the data by searchsorted's index is most likely going to be larger than the difference between bisect and mergesorted to begin with. Plus RAM.

(but 5/5 Bi Rico for finding out its the format thats the problem)

Comment: @user3329564 I believe there was a patch to fix this at some point, but don't remember which version it got into.

Comment: I am using numpy `1.10.1` and i am getting the opposite behavior: `timeit a['f0'].searchsorted(400.)` is `best of 3: 8.1 µs per loop` and `timeit f0.searchsorted(400.)` is `best of 3: 510 ns per loop`. I wonder why that is.

Comment: @snowleopard I'm not sure I understand your question. I believe a fix has been added to numpy to make the difference between `a['f0'].searchsorted` and `f0.searchsorted` much smaller. They're never going to be the same, but the 1000x performance difference has been removed.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some code to illustrate the size of problem (as of 11th May 2015) and how to 'fix' it.

```
import numpy as np
import bisect
import timeit
from random import randint

dtype = np.dtype([ ('pos','<I'),('sig','<H') ])             # my data is unsigned 32bit, and unsigned 16bit
data1 = np.fromfile('./all2/840d.0a9b45e8c5344abf6ac761017e93b5bb.2.1bp.binary', dtype)

dtype2 = np.dtype([('pos',np.uint32),('sig',np.uint32)])    # convert data to both unsigned 32bit
data2 = data1.astype(dtype2)

data3 = data2.view(('uint32', len(data2.dtype.names)))    # convert above to a normal array (not structured array)

print data1.dtype.descr # [('pos', '<u4'), ('sig', '<u2')]
print data2.dtype.descr # [('pos', '<u4'), ('sig', '<u4')]
print data3.dtype.descr # [('', '<u4')]

print data1.nbytes  # 50344494
print data2.nbytes  # 67125992
print data3.nbytes  # 67125992

print data1['pos'].max() # 2099257376
print data2['pos'].max() # 2099257376
print data3[:,0].max()   # 2099257376

def b1():   return bisect.bisect_left(data1['pos'],           randint(100000000,200000000))
def b2():   return bisect.bisect_left(data2['pos'],           randint(100000000,200000000))
def b3():   return bisect.bisect_left(data3[:,0],             randint(100000000,200000000))
def ss1():  return np.searchsorted(data1['pos'],              randint(100000000,200000000))
def ss2():  return np.searchsorted(data2['pos'],              randint(100000000,200000000))
def ss3():  return np.searchsorted(data3[:,0],                randint(100000000,200000000))

def ricob1():   return bisect.bisect_left(data1['pos'], np.uint32(randint(100000000,200000000)))
def ricob2():   return bisect.bisect_left(data2['pos'], np.uint32(randint(100000000,200000000)))
def ricob3():   return bisect.bisect_left(data3[:,0],   np.uint32(randint(100000000,200000000)))
def ricoss1():  return np.searchsorted(data1['pos'],    np.uint32(randint(100000000,200000000)))
def ricoss2():  return np.searchsorted(data2['pos'],    np.uint32(randint(100000000,200000000)))
def ricoss3():  return np.searchsorted(data3[:,0],      np.uint32(randint(100000000,200000000)))

print timeit.timeit(b1,number=300)  # 0.0085117816925
print timeit.timeit(b2,number=300)  # 0.00826191902161
print timeit.timeit(b3,number=300)  # 0.00828003883362
print timeit.timeit(ss1,number=300) # 6.57477498055
print timeit.timeit(ss2,number=300) # 5.95308589935
print timeit.timeit(ss3,number=300) # 5.92483091354

print timeit.timeit(ricob1,number=300)  # 0.00120902061462
print timeit.timeit(ricob2,number=300)  # 0.00120401382446
print timeit.timeit(ricob3,number=300)  # 0.00120711326599
print timeit.timeit(ricoss1,number=300) # 4.39265394211
print timeit.timeit(ricoss2,number=300) # 0.00116586685181
print timeit.timeit(ricoss3,number=300) # 0.00108909606934
```

*Update!*
So thanks to Rico's comments, it seems like setting the type for the number you want to searchsorted/bisect is really import!
However, on the structured array with 32bit and 16bit ints, its still slow (although no where near as slow as before)

Comment: You're confusing a few things here. First, your code, as you've posted it here, will not run so I need to just guess at what your timings actually represent. I don't think `data3` is what you think it is, I believe (afaict from your non working code) it is a size (2,) array.

Second, numpy does a lot of magic in order to be able to support all sorts of data types. The issue you have here is not so much with structured arrays, but with data types. Your search target `2000000000` is going to be treated as an `int64` by numpy, so all your search arrays will need to be up-converted.

Comment: Numpy's support for all sorts of data types is awesome when it just works. However, in some cases, especially when you're one is trying to optimize some performance critical code, it's a bit of a pain. Understanding what types are being used and when arrays are quietly being copied is key to maximum performance.

Comment: Sorry the code didn't work - i edited it later to add data2, and left in a 'numpy.' rather than a 'np.' - sorry about that.
Changing the type made a huge difference! I'm going to have to go through all my code now and check this!!! :D